# Practical algorithm for testing whether an edge is Delaunay

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I have a set of vertices $V$ and a set of segments $S$. I want to know whether a segment in the set $S$ is *Delaunay* against the vertices in $V$.

I would like to state my assumed definition of a *Delaunay edge*: An edge is *Delaunay*, iff there exists a circumsphere of its endpoints not containing any other vertex *inside* it.

I would like to know *practical* approaches/algorithms for such *Delaunay-edge* test.

Comment: In case of not getting any answer, would it be better to cross post this question to CSTheory.SE?

Comment: I have posted this question on CSTheory.SE